# Add custom headers to Apache HttpClient CONNECT request

Tags: java, http, proxy, http-headers, apache-httpclient-4.x

I have a ProxyMesh configuration working with a Java project and Apache HttpClient, the default configuration works fine with HTTPS requests, I now need to add a custom header only to be read by the proxy, according to the [docs](https://docs.proxymesh.com/article/145-proxy-server-requests-over-https) this must be done on the CONNECT request, I added an interceptor on the HttpClientBuilder, but the header is only being included in the GET request, not in the initial CONNECT request (I checked using Wireshark). Is there a place I can setup the CONNECT request header in the HttpClient?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Managed to make it work, using HttpClientBuilder.setRequestExecutor(new CustomHttpRequestExecutor()) and on the CustomHttpRequestExecutor I had to override the preProcess method.

```
@Override
void preProcess(HttpRequest request, HttpProcessor processor, HttpContext context) throws HttpException, IOException {

    if ("CONNECT".equalsIgnoreCase(request.getRequestLine().getMethod())) {
        request.setHeader("headername","value")
    }
    super.preProcess(request, processor, context)
}
```